# Which one is better Client-Side OAuth Flow or Server-Side OAuth Flow

Tags: angularjs, node.js, oauth

I am working on a MEAN Stack application which would implement OAuth with various service providers.

I would like to know whether Client-Side OAuth FLow would be a better or a Server-Side OAuth Flow in terms of Security Implications.

Also, i would like to have the functionality to link with these account permanently in my app, so that the app could make api calls to these account, should i save the access tokens in my app for using them later on?

Comment: Thanks @K.Toress , also can you let me know if it would be a great idea to store access tokens and refresh tokens in my app. If not then would i have to always make the new authenticated calls to the service providers every time users logs into my app.